# Using page-something.php as static front page

Tags: pages, templates

I have created 2 pages inside wordpress "blog" and "hpage", on the config I have set static front page to "hpage" as initial page and "blog" for posts index.

Now I want to create a "page-hpage.php" file to create a really especific front page. Looking for the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) I see that I can use "page-$slug.php", but "page-hpage.php" just doesn't work but if I use "page-$id.php" using the id of the "hpage" I work.

Now, If I install this template again the page is likely to not have the same ID again, so it will fail. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that your page slug is actually called `hpage`. do `var_dump( get_queried_object()->post_name );` in your header and check the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'front-page.php' for your template. You can read more about it at https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Or create a page template that you set in the editor. This will allow you to set it on any page and you're not tied to the ID.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

[image: Page Template]

Comment: This means that there is no way to achieve what I want without using front-page ?

Comment: Updated to include page templates without ID.